# Transition time in css slider

Tags: css, slider

I have created  slider based on this pen:

https://codepen.io/davidhc/pen/DbYENj

```
<div class='slider'>
<div class='slide1'></div>
<div class='slide2'></div>
<div class='slide3'></div>
</div>

.slider {
 max-width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 position: relative;
 }
.slide1,.slide2,.slide3,.slide4,.slide5 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 }
.slide1 {
 background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946   /580x0-9_cropped_1371566801_p17tbs0rrjqdt1u4dnk94fe4b63.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
 animation:fade 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 8s infinite;

 } 
.slide2 {
 background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371565525_p17tbqpu0d69c21hetd77dh483.jpeg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
 animation:fade2 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade2 8s infinite;
}
.slide3 {
background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371564896_p17tbq6n86jdo3ishhta3fv1i3.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
animation:fade3 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade
{
0%   {opacity:1}
33.333% { opacity: 0}
66.666% { opacity: 0}
100% { opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fade2
{
0%   {opacity:0}
33.333% { opacity: 1}
66.666% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes fade3
{
0%   {opacity:0}
33.333% { opacity: 0}
66.666% { opacity: 1}
100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

I know I can adjust the transition time from 8s to my wish, but how can I adjust the time it takes to fade in and out? I would like a little faster easing in and out, but make each slider image stay visible longer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make the fade in and out more faster, you can use smaller percentages for the opacity changes, like a,

```
@keyframes fade { 0% {opacity:1} 10% {opacity:0} 90% { opacity:0} 100% {opacity:1} }
```

It will make the element fade out in 0.8S and fade in 0.8S,leaving 6.4 Seconds of full opacity.

if you need to slow down animation part you can do it with increasing and decreasing the opacity value as well.

Comment: That did not work well, the images are jumping now...